# “the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used” warning from nested `if elses' over a dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement, mapply

I have a dataframe with two columns, Q10_headache_tibble:

```
structure(list(df_questionaire.headaches = c(0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L), df_questionaire.headaches_covid = c(0L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, NA, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 774L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 774L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 774L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 774L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 774L, 0L, 0L, 
774L)), row.names = c(NA, -175L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I created a function that should return a character vector (Q10_incidence) the same length as nrow(df_headache_tibble), based on nested conditions that should be applied to the dataframe, rowwise. Q10_incidence[i] should be the result of applying the function to the df_headache_tibble[i,1] and df_headache_tibble[i,2], for which I intended to use mapply.

```
incidence_headaches<-function(x,y){
        if (is.na(x)|is.na(y)){
                        output<-NA
                }
        else if (x==2){
                if (y==2){
                        output<-'previous_headache_maintained'
                }else if(y==0){
                        output<-'previous_headache_ceased'
                }
        }else if(x %in% c(0,774,775,776)){
                if (y==2){
                        output<-'new_onset_headache'
                }else if (y %in% c(0, 774, 775, 776)){
                        output<-'no_headache'
                }
        }
}

Q10_incidence<-mapply(incidence_headaches, Q10_headache_tibble[,1], Q10_headache_tibble[,2])
```

When I call

```
mapply(incidence_headaches, Q10_headache_tibble[,1], Q10_headache_tibble[,2])
```

I get the dreadful "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" in several warnings. How could I handle this?
Although I found several questions about the same "condition has length (...)" warning, I still find this topic quite confusing. A "for dummies" walkthrough is welcomed.

It seems to have something to do with vectorization, and may be solved by substituting the function with a nested ifelse() structure, which could be very messy.

I may need to use similar functions on many occasions, not so sure what is the best workaround.

Comment: If any of the function's inputs `x` or `y` is a vector of length > 1, then any of `is.na(x)` or `is.na(y)` is a vector of the same length, hence the warning. The solution is to use `ifelse`. Can you go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Personally I try to do as much R as I can with only a small subset of its many commands. Maybe a simple `apply` is an easier way to manage this. `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` will give each row pf your data.frame to a function. So I made this slight change to your function (just the first 3 lines are of interest here, the rest is copy&paste):

```
incidence_headaches<-function(row){
  x <- row[1]
  y <- row[2]
  if (is.na(x)|is.na(y)){
    output<-NA
  }
  else if (x==2){
    if (y==2){
      output<-'previous_headache_maintained'
    }else if(y==0){
      output<-'previous_headache_ceased'
    }
  }else if(x %in% c(0,774,775,776)){
    if (y==2){
      output<-'new_onset_headache'
    }else if (y %in% c(0, 774, 775, 776)){
      output<-'no_headache'
    }
  }
}
```

You can then use simple `apply` like this:

```
apply(df_headache_tibble, MARGIN = 1, incidence_headaches)
```

To get something like this:

```
> apply(df_headache_tibble, MARGIN = 1, incidence_headaches)
  [1] "no_headache"                  "previous_headache_ceased"     "previous_headache_maintained"
  [4] "previous_headache_maintained" "new_onset_headache"           "no_headache"                 
  [7] "no_headache"                  "no_headache"                  "previous_headache_ceased"    
 [10] "new_onset_headache"           "previous_headache_ceased"     "previous_headache_maintained"
 [13] "no_headache"                  "previous_headache_ceased"     "no_headache" 
...
```

**2)** `mapply` is obviously a perfectly working function and there is no reason not to use it. Your problem was: tibbles are data.frames but they do not behave like data.frames. This works well:

```
mapply(incidence_headaches, 
       as.data.frame(df_headache_tibble)[,1],
       as.data.frame(df_headache_tibble)[,2])
```

When you subset only one row from a data.frame, it will give you a vector, when you subset only one row from a tibble, it will give you a tibble. Hadley has a different opinion on how things should work then the people who invented the R data.frame. There are ways around this as in

```
mapply(incidence_headaches, 
       df_headache_tibble[,1, drop = TRUE],
       df_headache_tibble[,2, drop = TRUE])
```

Read details here but mostly be always aware, that although tibbles are data.frames they do not behave exactly like data.frames: https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/subsetting.html

Comment: Bernhard, Although you got the desired output, did not you get the warnings all the same?

Comment: I do not get warnings. Neither with my **1)** which uses an adapted function with `apply` nor with my **2)** which uses `mapply` just as you intended but with proper data.frames not with tibbles.

Comment: As @Bernhard wrote, it was all about the weird handling of single rows in tibbles, the solution was simple. Not so sure why I was using tibbles anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fully vectorized solution that doesn't need a `*apply` loop.

```
incidence_headaches <- function(x, y){
  # create the return vector
  output <- rep('no_headache', NROW(x))
  # conditions for 'x'
  x_2 <- x == 2
  x_vec <- x %in% c(0, 774, 775, 776)
  # conditions for 'y'
  y_2 <- y == 2
  y_vec <- y %in% c(0, 774, 775, 776)
  # assign the return values given a combination
  # of the conditions above. Note that the
  # condition y == 0 is only used once and
  # therefore a logical vector is not needed
  output[is.na(x) | is.na(y)] <- NA_character_
  output[x_2 & y_2] <- 'previous_headache_maintained'
  output[x_2 & y == 0] <- 'previous_headache_ceased'
  output[x_vec & y_2] <- 'new_onset_headache'
  output[x_vec & y_vec] <- 'no_headache'
  # return to caller
  output
}

Q10_incidence <- incidence_headaches(Q10_headache_tibble[, 1], Q10_headache_tibble[, 2])
head(Q10_incidence)
#[1] "no_headache"                  "previous_headache_ceased"    
#[3] "previous_headache_maintained" "previous_headache_maintained"
#[5] "no_headache"                  "no_headache"
```